# Android to JSON to PHP to MySQL Single Layout View

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I've been working on a app for about two weeks now, I've been able to connect and pull data from json, with php and mysql. Now It seems I've made some type of error were it keeps telling me that "Required field(s) is missing" in witch is one of my if statements in my php, I'm able to view the content if I access the php page via web using the string get, I've tried hard coding it in my Android so I can at least test to see if it can pull the data, but I keep getting the same message error, any help would be appreciated. thanks.

**ViewListingDetails.java**:

```
package com.listing.spot.listings;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.listing.spot.R;

public class ViewListingDetails  extends Activity implements OnClickListener{



            String id_rs;
            String textTo;
            TextView txtID;
            TextView txtDetails;


            // Progress Dialog
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;

            // JSON parser class
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

            // single product url
            private static final String url_product_detials = "http://adsinsac.com/realtors/droid/listings/homes/listing_details.php";

            // JSON Node names
            private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
            private static final String TAG_TABLE = "listing";

            private static final String TAG_ID = "id_rs";
            private static final String TAG_DISCRIPTION = "description_rs";


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.view_listing_details);

            // Getting complete product details in background thread
            new GetProductDetails().execute();

            // getting product details from intent
            Intent i = getIntent();

            // getting product id (pid) from intent
            id_rs = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);

        }

        /**
         * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
         * */
        class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewListingDetails.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading Listing Details. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Getting product details in background thread
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Check for success tag
                        int success;
                        try {
                            // Building Parameters
                            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


                            String HT ;

                            HT= "5004";

                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_rs", HT));

                            // getting product details by making HTTP request
                            // Note that product details url will use GET request
                            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                    url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                            // check your log for json response
                            Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                            // json success tag
                            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                            if (success == 1) {
                                // successfully received product details
                                JSONArray productObj = json
                                        .getJSONArray(TAG_TABLE); // JSON Array

                                // get first product object from JSON Array
                                JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);


                                // product with this pid found
                                // Edit Text

                                txtID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDetailID);
                                txtDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDetails);
                                //txtPrayBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrayRequest);
                                /*
                                txtPrayFrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtYourName);
                                txtPrayerMade = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_num_prayers);
                                */

                                // display product data in EditText
                                txtID.setText(product.getString(TAG_ID));
                                txtDetails.setText(product.getString(TAG_DISCRIPTION));
                                /*
                                txtPrayBody.setText(product.getString(TAG_BODY));
                                txtPrayFrom.setText(product.getString(TAG_FOOTER));
                                txtPrayerMade.setText(product.getString(TAG_NUM_PRAYERS));
                                */

                            }else{
                                // product with pid not found
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                return null;
            }


            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once got all details
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

**JSON**:

```
{
success: 1,
listing: [
{
id_rs: "5000",
user_id_rs: "1",
retype_rs: "Residential",
price_rs: "515000",
city_rs: "Folsom",
state_rs: "CA",
country_rs: "United States",
description_rs: "GORGEOUS SINGLE STORY NEAR WILLOW SPRINGS RESERVOIR! SALT WATER, PEBBLE TECH POOL W/WATER FEATURE*PRIVATE BACKYARD*LOGGIA*SPACIOUS PATIO & GRASS AREA*BEAUTIFUL KITCHEN OPEN TO FAMILY ROOM W/FIREPLACE*MAPLE CABS*GRANITE COUNTERS*SS GE PROFILE APPLIANCES*TRAVERTINE & HANDSCRAPED WALNUT FLRS*PLANTATION SHUTTERS*SILHOUETTE BLINDS*CROWN MOLDING*CEILING FANS*UPGRADED & RECESSED LIGHTS* BATH SPORTS VESSEL SINK & GRANITE COUNTER*STEPS FROM BEAUTIFUL PRESERVE AND WALKING TRAILS*NEAR INTEL & SHOPPING! Read more on REALTOR.com: 1033 Pintail Cir, Folsom, CA 95630 -",
bedrooms_rs: "4",
bathrooms_rs: "2",
builtin_rs: "",
resize_rs: "2125",
contact_name_rs: "Admin",
contact_phone_rs: "(916) 591-8987",
contact_email_rd: "apps4nerds@gmail.com",
contact_website_rd: "",
contact_address_rd: "230 Spring Oak Ct Folsom CA",
cover_image_rs: "http://adsinsac.com/realtors/uploads/l262fbe44-m0x_1402076456.jpg",
pictures_rs: "http://adsinsac.com/realtors/uploads/l262fbe44-m0x_1402076456.jpg::http://adsinsac.com/realtors/uploads/l262fbe44-m1x_1402076459.jpg::http://adsinsac.com/realtors/uploads/l262fbe44-m2x_1402076461.jpg::http://adsinsac.com/realtors/uploads/l262fbe44-m3x_1402076463.jpg::http://adsinsac.com/realtors/uploads/l262fbe44-m4x_1402076469.jpg::http://adsinsac.com/realtors/uploads/l262fbe44-m4x_1402076472.jpg::http://adsinsac.com/realtors/uploads/l262fbe44-m5x_1402076474.jpg::http://adsinsac.com/realtors/uploads/l262fbe44-m6x_1402076477.jpg::http://adsinsac.com/realtors/uploads/l262fbe44-m7x_1402076479.jpg::",
dttm_rs: "2014-06-06 13:39:38",
dttm_modified_rs: "2014-06-06 13:39:38",
apt_rs: "",
postal_rd: "95630",
subtype_rs: "House",
classification_rs: "Sale",
headline_rs: "1033 Pintail Cir",
address_rd: "1033 Pintail Cir",
latitude_rd: "38.651113",
longitude_rd: "-121.146177",
listing_expire_rd: "2014-08-21",
listing_type_rd: "1"
}
]
}
```

**PHP**:

```
 <?php

$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once '../lib/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listing WHERE id = $id");

   if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $daftar_rs = array();
            $daftar_rs["id_rs"] = $result["id"];
            $daftar_rs["user_id_rs"] = $result["user_id"];
            $daftar_rs["retype_rs"] = $result["retype"];
            $daftar_rs["price_rs"] = $result["price"];
            $daftar_rs["price_rs"] = $result["price"];
            $daftar_rs["city_rs"] = $result["city"];
            $daftar_rs["state_rs"] = $result["state"];
            $daftar_rs["country_rs"] = $result["country"];     
            $daftar_rs["description_rs"] = $result["description"];  
            $daftar_rs["bedrooms_rs"] = $result["bedrooms"];
            $daftar_rs["bathrooms_rs"] = $result["bathrooms"];  
            $daftar_rs["builtin_rs"] = $result["builtin"];
            $daftar_rs["resize_rs"] = $result["resize"];
            $daftar_rs["contact_name_rs"] = $result["contact_name"];
            $daftar_rs["contact_phone_rs"] = $result["contact_phone"];
            $daftar_rs["contact_email_rd"] = $result["contact_email"];
            $daftar_rs["contact_website_rd"] = $result["contact_website"];
            $daftar_rs["contact_address_rd"] = $result["contact_address"];
            $daftar_rs["contact_address_rd"] = $result["contact_address"];
            $daftar_rs["cover_image_rs"] = $result["cover_image"];
            $daftar_rs["pictures_rs"] = $result["pictures"];
            $daftar_rs["dttm_rs"] = $result["dttm"];
            $daftar_rs["dttm_modified_rs"] = $result["dttm_modified"];
            $daftar_rs["apt_rs"] = $result["apt"];
            $daftar_rs["postal_rd"] = $result["postal"];
            $daftar_rs["apt_rs"] = $result["apt"];
            $daftar_rs["subtype_rs"] = $result["subtype"];
            $daftar_rs["classification_rs"] = $result["classification"];
            $daftar_rs["headline_rs"] = $result["headline"];
            $daftar_rs["address_rd"] = $result["address"];
            $daftar_rs["latitude_rd"] = $result["latitude"];
            $daftar_rs["longitude_rd"] = $result["longitude"];
            $daftar_rs["listing_expire_rd"] = $result["listing_expire"];
            $daftar_rs["listing_type_rd"] = $result["listing_type"];

             // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["listing"] = array();

            array_push($response["listing"], $daftar_rs);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: u getting json when u hit the php on broswer right?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code is expecting a parameter called `id` and you are sending `id_rs`.

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
  //....
}
```

Android:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_rs", HT));
```

You need both of them to be `id` or `id_rs` for receiving the expected result.

Comment: Since both PHP and Android code are by one person, it is that person's liberty to decide the name of the parameter. Suggesting one or the other would be limiting the choice.

Comment: Well that's true, and I think that would be too much hand-holding. But a *suggestion* (between one of the two he wrote) won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Well your json is invalid, all stings including keys have to be be wrapped in double quotes. I don't see why they aren't there, but you can always force them by adding them manually.